# Java JSP , перенаполнение аттрибута (setAttribute)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlet

Здравствуйте есть сервлет внутри сервлета устанавливается аттрибут data

```
req.setAttribute("data", list);
```

есть страница JSP которая выводит этот обьект

```html
<textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" style="position:absolute;left:469px;top:65px;width:552px;height:284px;z-index:17;" rows="16" cols="59" spellcheck="false">Вы находитесь на странице GIFTS, используйте формы ниже для взаимодействия

<%
  List data = (List)request.getAttribute("data");
  for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){out.println(data.get(i));}
%>
</textarea>
```

но при обновлении или обращение к этой странице в первый раз, обьект выводится как надо, но в последующие разы вместо того чтобы вывести тот же обьект с новыми данными  выводятся СТАРЫЕ + НОВЫЕ данные.

как это выглядит 1-ое обращение к странице : [image: 1ое обращение к странице]

2-ое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть я очищаю text-area но все равно выводятся старые данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в заполнении данными списка `list` перед `req.setAttribute("data", list);`.

Возможно: Эта переменная у Вас объявлена как

```
static List list = ...
```

то есть данные в ней накапливаются.

Объявите ее обычным членом класса, без `static`.

Comment: переменная обьявлена как List list = new ArrayList();

Comment: я идиот) ваш ответ подтолкнул меня посмотреть где собственно я заполняю этот обьект. а делаю я это методом .add . спасибо! вопрос решен

Comment: @IRAконсилиум Не угадал - :(. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.